# Azure Service fabric - upgrade takes very long

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a SF app and the build server pushes out an upgrade. Usually this takes about 15 mins or so but recently the times have been going up

Somewhere around #78 we switched to a new cluster - but it's the same config and same region (5 A1 servers).

For the latest one where it's been upgrading for more than an hour, on the fabric explorer, still the first node is being upgraded and couple of services have 1 unhealthy partition.

Any help/tips on how to get this to behave a little more consistently?

```
Build  ↑

Duration   

Agent   
In progress #82-master  1 hr 1 min and counting servicefabric
Success #81-master  50 min  servicefabric
Success #80-master  17 min  servicefabric
Success #79-master  15 min  servicefabric
Success #78-master  30 min  servicefabric
Success #77-master  14 min  servicefabric
Success #76-master  14 min  servicefabric
Success #75-master  6 min 21 sec    servicefabric
```

Comment: Is there was the same amount of data in collections and the same services got updated in all the upgrades?

Comment: Yes... There's hardly any data on the cluster... Only what's generated by a few tests

Comment: Are you using reliable services? If so, perhaps your reliable services are taking a very long time to shut down cleanly - according to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-introduction/#service-lifecycle under "Service Shutdown", Service Fabric waits indefinitely for RunAsync to return when shutdown is requested.

Comment: As @AdrianHofman has mentioned, what with cancellation tokens?